# php if else in WordPress template - is this php?

Tags: wordpress

In php I know todo  a if else like this

```
<?php 
if ($t<"10")
  {
  echo "Have a good morning!";
  }
else if ($t<"20")
  {
  echo "Have a good day!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Have a good night!";
  }
?>
```

but I see that in WordPress it is done like this on the  template and it looks more like vb.net. is this word press's own made up language?

```
<?php if(true) : ?>

  <span>true</span>

//html

<?php else : ?>

<span>else</span>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's native PHP.

It's for HTML templates; alternative syntax

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

This is php too. Just another way of writing an if-condition.

See this link for further information:
http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.elseif.php